# JS/HTML or FLASH action diagram displayer

Tags: javascript, html, flash, drawing, diagram

I'm already looking several hours for a tool that matches my requirements but can't seem to find anything.

The tool that I want (regardless of the technology) should be able to draw a diagram where actions are linked. Now the special things is that actions cannot only split up (then a regular tree would suffice), they can also merge down.

Example (2 & 3 link to 5; and 5 & 6 link to 7)

```
Action 1  -> Action 2  -> Action 5   -> action 7
          -> action 3
          -> action 4  -> Action 6
```

There are a lot of diagramming tools (jointJs, jGraph, jGraphUI, jsPlumb, ..) that work fine but the issue is that you need to specify yourself the coordinates of the items.

As the data is dynamic, it's too much work to specify this manually.
Do you know simple tools (no need to edit the diagram, just to display it) that possess of the functionality that I require? (as long as it can run in a web context it is fine, so JS, flash, canvas are all candidates)

Thanks,
Pj

Answer (score 2):

JGraph, you mention, does have automatic layouting, as does mxGraph, [github.com/jgraph/mxgraph](http://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph), the JavaScript version (and is free for non-commerical use)

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a commercial scenario, [yFiles for HTML](http://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) seems to be a good match for your requirements:

It is a pure Javascript diagramming solution that requires no active server component or plugin. It can easily deal with general graphs and has very sophisticated automatic layout algorithms.

There is a live demo on the website where you can try out your exact scenario:
Use an HTML5 capable browser and point it to:

[InteractiveGraphSource Demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/demos/DataBinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html),

wait until it loads, then switch to example 4 in the combobox at the top and fill in the following values into the textboxes on the right:

Nodes Source:

```
{
1:'Action 1', 
2:'Action 2', 
3:'Action 3',
4:'Action 4', 
5:'Action 5', 
6:'Action 6',
7:'Action 7'
}
```

Edges Source:

```
[
{from:1, to:2}, 
{from:2, to:5}, 
{from:3, to:5}, 
{from:6, to:7}, 
{from:5, to:7}, 
{from:1, to:3}, 
{from:4, to:6}, 
]
```

Source Node Binding:

```
from
```

Target Node Binding:

```
to
```

Make Node Id Binding and Edge Label Binding empty

And modify the template slightly like this:

```
<rect fill='AliceBlue' stroke='LightBlue' stroke-width='2' width='{TemplateBinding width}' height='{TemplateBinding height}'></rect><text transform='translate(10 20)' data-content='{Binding}' style='font-size:18px; font-family:Arial; fill:#000; text-anchor: left; dominant-baseline: central;'></text>
```

When you are done press the "Apply Graph Source" button at the top left and watch your graph being animated and displayed in the center canvas. You can then navigate the graph by panning with the mouse, zooming with the mouse wheel and selecting nodes by clicking them or use keyboard navigation to switch between the nodes.

This is just a demo of the library, but the demo is quite powerful already. You can also evaluate the library and do "real programming" against the huge API.

Disclosure: I work for yWorks, however I do not represent my employer here.

Comment: Hi there, this is exactly the solution we need, however we are a non-commerical (educational) organisation, and will probably not be able to afford this software.

are there open source variants that do the same?

Kind regards,
Pj